# Correcting an unexpected non-replacement of an argument in a function created in the code

Tags: r, function

First of all, it is my first question on stackoverflow. I tried to write my question (below) with some common sense (a descriptive title for others to search and find it easily, reproductible code, ...) but if there are any advise or corrections for future questions I would ask that would make it more practical for all of you to answer, please indicate it to me in the answers.

**The question :**

I managed to write some code giving me exactly what I want. That should not be a reason to ask a question on this board, however I have to copy-paste the same chunk many dozen times with only few and very predictibale modifications.

Therefore, I chose to write my own function to save time. This function failed depiste seeming to me just an expansion on previous techniques of building one's own function in a R script.

I cut donw the initial function in smaller pieces to understand what went wrong (and reduce the number of steps and arguments to put in) and found one peculiar part of the initial script that failed and I cannot work around.

Essentially, my questions come down to :

1. Why the argument "Variable" is not changed by the argument I specified when I run to function ?
2. How should I modify my script to correct that ?

**The code :**

(I'm not allowed to transmit any part of my database, so I use the gapminder dataset which contains variables with similar characteristics).

```
#Package

library(tidyverse)
library(questionr)
library(haven)
library(knitr)
library(tidyr)
library(qwraps2)
library(matrixStats)
library(reldist)
library(gapminder)

#Reproductible data

db <- gapminder

#Function

Liste <- function(Variable)
{
  Liste <-
  list(list("Minimum" = ~eval(parse(text = paste("min(",Variable," na.rm = TRUE"))),
            "Moyenne" = ~mean(Variable, na.rm = TRUE),
            "Mediane" = ~median(Variable, na.rm = TRUE),
            "Maximum" = ~max(Variable, na.rm = TRUE),
            "Caracteristiques position" = ~ifelse(mean(Variable, na.rm = TRUE)>median(Variable, na.rm = TRUE),"Moyenne > Mediane",ifelse(mean(Variable, na.rm = TRUE)<median(Variable, na.rm = TRUE),"Mediane > Moyenne","Moyenne = Mediane")),
            "Valeur manquante" = ~sum(is.na(Variable)),
            "D1" = ~quantile(Variable, 0.1, na.rm = TRUE),
            "Q25" = ~quantile(Variable, 0.25, na.rm = TRUE),
            "Q75" = ~quantile(Variable, 0.75, na.rm = TRUE),
            "D9" = ~quantile(Variable, 0.9, na.rm = TRUE)
  ))
}


Liste_Test <- Liste(Variable = lifeExp)
```

**Summing-up the problem**

If you open the object "Liste_Test", instead of replacing "Variable" by "lifeExp", nothing changes. It prevents the rest of the function to properly work.

You might notice the first element of the list created is different:

```
"Minimum" = ~eval(parse(text = paste("min(",Variable," na.rm = TRUE")))
```

It is a first try using so close questions in the StackOverflow board. The resultat is exactly the same.

I also found some answer recommanding using the function "do.call". However, I cannot understand how it is supposed to work and therefore what kind of modification I should do.
To give you an idea of the expected result, you can add this chunk (not in the form of a function) to the previous script.

I hope I provided a complete although not too long explaination of my problem and questions.

Comment: This is a strong first question, but I wish your example was more **minimal** - I don't think you're using almost any of the package you have `library()` calls for. I don't have `questionr`, `reldist`, or `qwraps2` installed. But I don't think you're using any packages except `gapminder` for the sample data and `purrr` (loaded by `tidyverse`) for the `~` function syntax. Maybe you could delete the rest of the `library` calls?

Comment: I'd also encourage you to make the problem minimal - is `list("Minimum" = ~eval(parse(text = paste("min(",Variable," na.rm = TRUE"))),"Moyenne" = ~mean(Variable, na.rm = TRUE)` enough? Or do you really need 9 more statistics? But this is just feedback on *how* you asked the question - which overall is quite good for a first question.

Comment: Thank you for the feedback concerning the way I wrote the question. I thought about the amount of packages I put in the code but it was in the first draft that most (maybe not all) made sense. I forgot to update the list when I removed the declinaison of this question with weighted functions.
Concerning the lenght of the code, I will reduce it next time since going from a list of two statistics to a larger list in just an expansion of what can be done providing a solution is found.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you pass column names as an argument to function you need to code things differently than you normally do. (Read about non-standard evaluation)

You are passing `Liste(Variable = lifeExp)` but R does not know what `lifeExp` is (Type it in the console and see what you get).

To keep things simple pass values instead of column name here.

```
Liste <- function(Variable)
{
    list("Minimum" = min(Variable, na.rm = TRUE),
         "Moyenne" = mean(Variable, na.rm = TRUE),
         "Mediane" = median(Variable, na.rm = TRUE),
         "Maximum" = max(Variable, na.rm = TRUE),
         "Caracteristiques position" = ifelse(mean(Variable, na.rm = TRUE) > 
                median(Variable, na.rm = TRUE),"Moyenne > Mediane",
                ifelse(mean(Variable, na.rm = TRUE) < median(Variable, na.rm = TRUE),
          "Mediane > Moyenne","Moyenne = Mediane")),
          "Valeur manquante" = sum(is.na(Variable)),
          "D1" = quantile(Variable, 0.1, na.rm = TRUE),
          "Q25" = quantile(Variable, 0.25, na.rm = TRUE),
          "Q75" = quantile(Variable, 0.75, na.rm = TRUE),
          "D9" = quantile(Variable, 0.9, na.rm = TRUE))
    
}
```

and then you can call this function as :

```
Liste(db$lifeExp)
```

Comment: Thank you for this answer. It is the answer with the closer proximity from the original way I wrote my code so I built on it (I will post how I used the answers to obtain the result I was looking for).
Looking at how you rewrote it, I think I will drop using the `summary_table` function from the `qwarps2` package. By the way, I did not paste the entire original example script. It explains why I did not name the data.frame of origin in the function, just the variable in it.

Answer (score 0):

Using `rlang`'s `ensym` we can quote the name i.e you can pass the name the way you did without quotes and handle it correctly a baseR alternative would be to use `deparse(substitute(Variable))`. the issue you had with your code is that you passed `lifeExp` instead of `"lifeExp"` and if you passed the variable name correctly how would you handle it on the other side without having access to the `data.frame`?

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(rlang)
sommaire <- function(df, Variable){
  Variable <- ensym(Variable)
  df %>%
     summarise(Minimum = min(!!Variable, na.rm=T), Moyenne = mean(!!Variable, na.rm=T), Mediane= median(!!Variable, na.rm=T), 
        Maximum = max(!!Variable, na.rm=T), `Caracteristiques position` = sprintf("Moyenne %s Mediane", case_when(Moyenne > Mediane ~ ">", Moyenne==Mediane ~ "=", T ~ "<")),
        `Valeur manquante` = sum(is.na(!!Variable)), data=list(set_names(quantile(!!Variable, c(.1, .25, .75, .9), na.rm=T), c("D1", "Q25", "Q75", "D9")))) %>%
         unnest_wider(data)
}

sommaire(db, lifeExp)
# A tibble: 1 x 10
  Minimum Moyenne Mediane Maximum `Caracteristiques position` `Valeur manquante`    D1   Q25   Q75    D9
    <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl> <chr>                                    <int> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
1    23.6    59.5    60.7    82.6 Moyenne < Mediane                            0  41.5  48.2  70.8  75.1
```

You could apply this to all numeric vars using `purrr::map`:

```r
map(set_names(colnames(db)[sapply(db, is.numeric)]), sommaire, df=db)  %>% bind_rows(.id="Variable")
# A tibble: 4 x 11
  Variable  Minimum    Moyenne   Mediane      Maximum `Caracteristiques position` `Valeur manquante`       D1       Q25        Q75         D9
  <chr>       <dbl>      <dbl>     <dbl>        <dbl> <chr>                                    <int>    <dbl>     <dbl>      <dbl>      <dbl>
1 year       1952       1980.     1980.        2007   Moyenne = Mediane                            0   1957      1966.      1993.      2002  
2 lifeExp      23.6       59.5      60.7         82.6 Moyenne < Mediane                            0     41.5      48.2       70.8       75.1
3 pop       60011   29601212.  7023596.  1318683096   Moyenne > Mediane                            0 946367.  2793664   19585222.  54801370. 
4 gdpPercap   241.      7215.     3532.      113523.  Moyenne > Mediane                            0    688.     1202.      9325.     19449.
```

Comment: Thank you for this answer. It is close to what I looked for, particularly the second script for what I’ve in mind as a first step (having a first overview of a set of variables in my database).
The reason why I do not name the data.frame of origin of the variable is because I initially use the function `summary_table` from the package `qwarps2`. I just notice I did not paste the entire code, hence the absence of an exemple of what I want to have at the end and an correct illustration of why only wanted to name the variable without naming the data.frame of origin.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all for the answers.

I also apologise for not pasting the entire example script (my mistake, bad double-check before clicking on the submit button). Part of the reason I choose to write the function that way come from me using the `summary_table` from the `qwarps2` package. The answer you provided allows me to drop using the function and package which make the whole thing nittier.

Here how I used your answer to solve my problem.

**Strategy**

I formated my initial try so that the results shows vertically rather than horizontally because I want to use them in RMarkdown for reports and working paper and this format is mor convenient for me.

Therefore, I proceeded in two steps :

1. Modifying my initial function to make it functional ;
2. Create a function to produce it in the right format (maybe over-convulated).

**Amended initial function**

```
Liste <- function(Variable)
{
  list("Minimum" = min(Variable, na.rm = TRUE),
       "Moyenne" = mean(Variable, na.rm = TRUE),
       "Mediane" = median(Variable, na.rm = TRUE),
       "Maximum" = max(Variable, na.rm = TRUE),
       "Position" = ifelse(mean(Variable, na.rm = TRUE) > 
                                              median(Variable, na.rm = TRUE),"Moyenne > Mediane",
                                            ifelse(mean(Variable, na.rm = TRUE) < median(Variable, na.rm = TRUE),
                                                   "Mediane > Moyenne","Moyenne = Mediane")),
       "Presente" = sum(!is.na(Variable))
       "Manquante" = sum(is.na(Variable)),
       "D1" = quantile(Variable, 0.1, na.rm = TRUE),
       "Q25" = quantile(Variable, 0.25, na.rm = TRUE),
       "Q75" = quantile(Variable, 0.75, na.rm = TRUE),
       "D9" = quantile(Variable, 0.9, na.rm = TRUE))
  
}
```

**Complementary function (Vertical format)**

```
Sommaire <- function(Variable)
{
  Tableau <- as.data.frame(Liste(Variable))
  Tableau <- data.frame(t(Tableau[-1]))
  return(Tableau)
}
```

Once again, thank you all for the help